# How to declare foreign benefits in German tax refund?

Tags: germany, benefits, income-tax-refund

I did an internship in Germany last year and now I am trying to fill the tax refund papers with the Elster online tool. I received the summary of paid taxes etc. from the company and my German income should be now correctly filled in the forms.

I come from Finland and last year I also received Finnish student allowance from which 10 % tax was automatically deducted by the state. With which form do I declare these foreign benefits? I didn't have other jobs during the year.

I also need to fill the Finnish tax return papers as they don't have the information about my German income yet. The Finnish tax authorities will apparently make sure that no double taxation occurs.